# Multiple output files from one input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dom

I'm trying to take this file input, which is a multi-file input.

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple=""/>
```

And after my files are selected, i want to put them into separate individual file inputs via javascript.  Is this possible?

Comment: Didn't you just ask a similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636064/javascript-file-upload-fields-manipulating-file-input

Comment: What is the business or programming problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps there is a different coding approach that we could help you with if you explain what you need to do.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?  Some other workaround?  I am faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, no. Every modern browser will prevent you from programmatically populating a file input.